# Proper way to package a react component library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

Right now, I'm working on a React component library, which I want to deliver via npm to as many people as possible. I use `webpack` and `babel` for packaging and processing of my code. However, being fairly new to `webpack`, I don't know what the best way would be to go about packaging my library.

I'm planning to have a list of files in the `src` folder that will be individual components. How do I go about packaging them for people to grab from npm? My guess is to output them individually, so that people can import whatever they need. However, I want them to work with ES5 (which I think is what `babel` does with the `es2015` preset which I have installed). My files are as follows:

**webpack.config.js** (a couple of things were removed for brevity)

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Component1: __dirname + '/src/Component1.js',
        Component2: __dirname + '/src/Component2.js'
    },
    output: {
            path: __dirname + '/dist',
            filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

**Component1.js** (sample component, written to showcase an example)

```
import React from 'react';


export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return React.createElement('p',{className : 'Component1'}, 'This is a test component.');
    }
}
```

After running through `webpack`, I get a huge file with lots of overhead code added by it, but, from what I can tell, the code is compiled to ES5, which is my intention. Is this the proper way to do this? Can I avoid the overhead added by webpack?

I tried googling for answers, but the articles I found ([this](https://medium.com/@adrianli/the-idiot-s-guide-to-publishing-a-react-component-to-npm-2b66b1ac03e0) and [this](http://frontendinsights.com/how-create-react-component-publish-npm/) mainly) were a bit outdated and/or required me to use some plugin for `webpack`, which I'm not very comfortable with yet. I'd like to understand what I should be doing and why. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question and something that I agree should be covered a lot more. For your specific problem at hand:

1. [react-npm-boilerplate](https://github.com/juliancwirko/react-npm-boilerplate) on githhub
2. [This article](http://julian.io/creating-react-npm-packages-with-es2015/) covers the idea of the github site in detail

Comment: Great resources, both of them. From what I understand I don't actually need webpack to build the package and I should be using just `babel` for that. Meanwhile, if I decide to not use tests for a bit, I don't need anything else to compile my component library except for `babel` and the two presets I'm using, correct?

Comment: No, you don't actually need webpack but there is no reason not to use it. I would suggest using whatever build system you are comfortable with.

The big thing with npm packages is making sure your package.json file has a main entry pointing to whatever file is your export and/or have an index.js file in the root directory which can then export, usually what is in you lib or dist directory.

You mentioned having a lot of overhead using webpack, it sounds like you need to build in production mode, especially for react: https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/

Comment: Thanks again for the answer and the clarification. After much consideration, I'm probably dropping webpack until last minute before publishing, as it has caused me numerous problems and crashes due to memory issues. If I can just build and run everything with Babel until I'm ready to publish that's pretty good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as modules with vendors.

```
 

    var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            Component1: __dirname + '/src/Component1.js',
            Component2: __dirname + '/src/Component2.js',
            vendor: ['react'],
        },
        output: {
                path: __dirname + '/dist',
                filename: '[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            loaders: [{
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                }
            }]
        }
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: "vendor",
                minChunks: Infinity
            })
        ]
    };
```

You get a file vendor.js where will be react

more detail here https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding what this does. Could you explain it a bit further?

Comment: Reactjs exclude from Component1 and Component2 to file vendor.js . Component1 and Component2 will be only link on react.